# Calling a specific item onClick without clicking in gridview

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am developing a flipcard game. I have a gridview and each grid item is a viewflipper. Each ViewFlipper has one textview and one imageview. Clicking an item flips from textview to imageview in 3d animation. I want  to start  animation of another item after animation of viewflipper ends.(Note:I add click listener on viewflipper in adapter class)

Here the adapter code:

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    int[]icons;
    Context context;
    int counter;
    View view = null;
    GridView grid;
     HashMap<String,View> hashMap;

    public MyGridViewAdapter(int[] icons,Context context,GridView grid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.icons=icons;
    this.context=context;
    this.grid=grid;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return icons[arg0];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int arg0, final View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        hashMap=new HashMap<String,View>();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

        if(arg1==null){
        view=new View(context);
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flipper, null);
        viewHolder.text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.picture);

        viewHolder.image.setImageResource(icons[arg0]);

        }else{
            view=(View)arg1;
        }
        final ViewFlipper  flipper = (ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.my_view_flipper);

         flipper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                AnimationFactory.flipTransition(flipper, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT,300);
                Animation animation=flipper.getInAnimation();

                animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {


                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        flipper.setEnabled(false);
                    }


                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }


                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        counter++;
                    hashMap.put(""+counter, v);
                        flipper.setEnabled(true);

                        Log.i("counter", ""+counter);
                AnimationFactory.flipTransition(flipper, FlipDirection.RIGHT_LEFT, 250);

                    }

                });
            }
            });
        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        private TextView text;
        private ImageView image;

    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry. It was comment for editing your question not for your question.

Comment: I store the view object in a hasmap when clicked an item and i increase the counter when clicked item and if counter%2==0 i get the firs object of hashmap for calling performclick of previous item but i get null pointer exception